# SQLite Cordova: "Error Processing SQL: undefined" with pre populated db

Tags: javascript, mysql, cordova

I followed this guide: http://www.corporatezen.com/2012/11/shipping-prepopulated-database-phonegap/

I have a pre populated db in /assets called coor_db.db

Following the guide I modified the code of my main activity file:

```
public class GoogleMaps extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);


        try {
            File dbFile = getDatabasePath("coor_db.db");
            if(!dbFile.exists()){
                this.copy("coor_db.db", dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {

         File CheckDirectory;
         CheckDirectory = new File(folder);

         String parentPath = CheckDirectory.getParent();

         File filedir = new File(parentPath);
         if (!filedir.exists()) {
             if (!filedir.mkdirs()) {
                 return;
             }
         }

        InputStream in = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        File newfile = new File(folder);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len; 
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

An then I create a js file where I try to open it and then try to make a query.

```
var coor_db = (function (){


    function init(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("coor_db", "1.0", "coor_db", 200000); 
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }   

    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

     //select all from coor_db
    function queryDB(tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM coor_db', [], querySuccess, errorQuery);
    }

    function errorQuery(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL query: "+err.code);
    }

    //handle the result
    function querySuccess(tx, result){

        alert("I'm called: "+result.rows.length);
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
            var row = result.rows.item(i);
            alert("id: "+row['id']+" lat: "+row['lat']);
            array[i] = {
                    id: row['id'],
                    text: row['lat']
            }
        }
        alert(array[2].id+" lat: "+array[2].text);

    }

    return {
        init : init
    }

})();
```

The error is raised by the method queryDB(tx).
I've tried to write coor_db.db instead of coor_db in
    var db = window.openDatabase("coor_db", "1.0", "coor_db", 200000);
but  it didn't change anything.

I have no clue about what is wrong.

In my index.js file I call coor_db.init()

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue :( did you ever figure it out? How can the err object be undefined in the error callback?

Comment: Sorry, I had no luck with this issue

Comment: I actually figured it out by logging the "transaction object" most commonly named "tx" in the official phonegap docs.